# Remove Javascript/ChildElement from WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control, children

I am using below code to inject javascript

```
HtmlElement head = _wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            HtmlElement scriptEl = _wb.Document.CreateElement("script"); 
            mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement element = (mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement; 
                        element.text = "function zoom(){document.body.style.zoom='150%';}"; 
            head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
```

Now can anyone tell me how to remove the added child

Answer (score 0):

I think explicit deleting of an element is not possible (did not check the IHTML interfaces on this).
But this can be done in 2 different ways too:

1. `element.OutherHtml = string.empty;` => removes the whole element but does not always work
2. `HtmlElement blankScript = _wb.Document.CreateElement("script");`
   `element = blankScript;` => replaces your unwanted script with a blank one